# spring mongo support for geoJSOn for 2dsphere index

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Mongo though provides 2dsphere index on legacy co-ordinates, the query requires to present to Point/Shapes in geoJSON format. For e.g., I have inserted the following records to address collection.

```js
{ "city" : "First",  "geo" : [ 13.45, 23.46 ] }
{ "city" : "Second", "geo" : [ 13.45, 20.46 ] }
```

Then I added 2dsphere index using following command as mongodb still allows 2dsphere index on legacy co-ordinates.

```js
db.address.ensureIndex({"geo":"2dsphere"})
```

Then if I do $near query using legacy format, but got an exception.

```js
> db.address.find({"geo":{$near:{"x":13.45,"y":23.45}}})
error: {
        "$err" : "can't parse query (2dsphere): { $near: { x: 13.45, y: 23.45 } }",
        "code" : 16535
}
```

But If do same query with geoJSON format, then I get result.

```js
> db.address.find({"geo":{$near:{"type":"Point",coordinates:[13.45,23.45]}}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("537306b4b8ac1f134d9efe89"), "city" : "First", "geo" : [ 13.45, 23.46 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("537306c3b8ac1f134d9efe8a"), "city" : "Second", "geo" : [ 13.45, 20.46 ] }
```

My question is, GeoConverters has all conversion made to legacy format. So, obviously they wont' work if I use 2dsphere index. Are there any converts available for geoJSON format. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Currently spring-data-mongo doesn't support the new mongo (> 2.4) 2dsphere indexes. There is a open issue on Jira about it:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1113?jql=project%20%3D%20DATAMONGO%20AND%20text%20~%20%22%24geometry%22

In the link you can find a gist link to example of how create such converters. You can use it or you can overcome this limitation creating a `@Query` with the query that you want that spring-data-mongo execute.

Regards.

avaz